# Surefire plugin reports from Cucumber test with reruns on examples

Tags: maven, testing, junit, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

I have an issue with report from rerun Cucumber failing scenarios using Surefire plugin.
There is standard configuration for plugin

```
           <configuration>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
           </configuration>
```

After first run test are reported correctly including scenario name and example number. So result from scenarios are:

- Example 1: Fail
- Example 2: Pass

Surefire trigger rerun for failed test run.
But report it as `"Example #1" classname="Examples"`
Number of test run visible in report is 3 (assume that test passed on rerun)
There is no matched with already existing and not interpreted as flaky.
It looks like bellow:

```
<testcase name="Login - After login session(...) - Example #1" classname="Login - After login session (...) - Examples" time="31.412">
    <failure>(...)</failure>
</testcase>

<testcase name="Login - After login session (...) - Examples - Example #2" classname="Login - After login session (...) - Examples" time="25.591"/>


<testcase name="Example #1" classname="Examples" time="12.615"/>
```

I checked `TestIdentifier` from Junit and in fact class name is `Examples` instead of the same as during first run

So the test are first run test running hierarchy looks like this (based on `testIdentifier.getDisplayName()`)

```
Cucumber (engine)
Login
Login - Some login scenario
Login - Some login scenario - Examples
Login - Some login scenario - Examples - Example #1.2
```

But rerun is like this

```
Cucumber (engine)
Login
Login - Some login scenario
Examples
Example #1.2
```

Which affect the surefire report.

Cucumber: 7.11.1

Surefire: 3.0.0-M9

Junit: 5.9.2

Do you have any idea for to make it work without playing with analysing/merging reports?

I've tried with Different configurations of Cucumber 7 and Junit 5.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Could you sprinkle some breakpoints in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/platform/engine/DefaultNamingStrategy.java and see what happens.

Comment: Or if you don't mind, create an issue with Cucumber JVM and attach a minimal reproducer as a GitHub Repo. You can use the skeleton as a starting point https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje checked place you pointed, for normal run it use `LONG` naming strategy, but during reruns it is `SHORT`. I've set the `cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long` on junit platform properties and now it looks ok :) Thank for that! Shouldn't it be default?

Comment: That's interesting. How did you configure the strategy previously?

Comment: It shouldn't be default. Ideally Surefire would use the tests ID rather than the human readable name to determine reruns. But in many ways they're stuck with the JUnit 4 assumptions.

Comment: And you can write an answer to your own post. This may be useful to other people.